# masterpages and css

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

i set some css rules and html tags, that looks desirable in the design view. But when a child form of the masterpage loads the page, it looks different. Can a child css rules dominate the properties of a parent css rules.

```
style type="text/css">
#container{position:relative;}
img#border{position:absolute; 

}
#placeH{position:absolute; left:344px;
    top: 325px;
    height: 168px;
    width: 708px;
    bottom:287px;
}
```

```
<title></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

```
<div align="center" id="container">
    <asp:Image ID="Header" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/header.png" Width="1196px" 
        Height="280px" />


  </div>
      <div id="border">

            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/border.png"/>// the border
```

that i try to set here appears fine in the masterpage design view..but on the childs 
design view,,it appears at the bottom left of the page

```
              </div>

                  <div id="placeH">
                         <form id="form1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

                           </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </form>

                  </div>
           </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only thing that I can see from here is that. You have some CSS that may not behave as you expect.

```
img#border{position:absolute;}
```

This will apply to an `<img/>` tag with the id="border". In the above HTML, you have an img inside a div with an id="border. You CSS for this should look something like.

```
div#border > img { postition:absolute; }  if you want it applied to the image only.
```

or

```
#border { position:absolute; } if you want it applied to the whole div.
```

It is actually quite hard to see in the above HTML with the snippets. If the above does not solve it, paste the whole thing for me.

Comment: I dont know what is the problem. i got that border image off the screen and set the whole thing to appear on the screen with no decoration but a header. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the style of `placeH` into this.

```
#placeH{
    position:absolute; 
    left:344px;
    top: 325px;
    height: 168px;
    width: 708px;
}
```

^^

And yes, css from master page is applied for the child page.